# Compare julian date with Normal date in SQL

Tags: sql-server, date

I am trying to convert a Julian date to Gregorian Date (`MM/DD/YYYY`) and compare it with a normal date:

```
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR, dbo.ConvertToGregDate(ExpDate), 101) < '04/01/2017'
```

This returns all the dates before 04/01 disregarding the year (e.g. the result will not include 04/02/2016 or 05/01/2016).

Is there anything different I should do here?

Comment: Why are you converting the dates to strings to do the comparisons?

Comment: you are comparing chars, not dates

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are comparing strings. If you are gonna do that, than you should use a date format that can be compared that way:

```
where convert(varchar(8), dbo.converttogregdate(ExpDate), 112) < '20170401'
```

Or better yet, don't convert your result to string at all:

```
where dbo.converttogregdate(ExpDate) < '20170401'
```